# Using TextWatcher to get values entered to two edittext and multiplying these values without a button. Automatic computation.

Tags: java, android, textwatcher

I want the app to automatically compute when the user enters the requested two values into edittext, without needing a button.

Is there a way to do it without using TextWatcher?

here is my attempt. Why doesnt it work? The app force shuts when a number is entered in edittext.

```
'

public class BodyMassIndex extends Activity

{

double result;
    EditText age, height, weight;

TextView tvResult;

int ageInt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bmi);
    initialize();

    TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            calculate();

        }



        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };

    height.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    weight.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

}

private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
    height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etHeight);
    weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etWeight);

    tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);


}

private void calculate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    double heightInt = 1;
    double weightInt = 0;

    if (height != null)
        heightInt = Double.parseDouble(height.getText().toString());

    if (weight != null)
        weightInt = Double.parseDouble(weight.getText().toString());

    result = weightInt / (heightInt * heightInt);
    String textResult = "Your BMI is " + result;
    tvResult.setText(textResult);




}}
'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the default values of the edittext to 0. Its probably force closing because you are trying to parse an empty string from an edittext that has nothing in it;

EDIT: try this

```
if (height != null)
    heightInt = Double.parseDouble(!height.getText().toString().equals("")?
           height.getText().toString() : "0");

if (weight != null)
    weightInt = Double.parseDouble(!weight.getText().toString().equals("")?
           weight.getText().toString() : "0");
```

this way your using a condition where no matter what youll be parsing a value that wont throw an exception

Comment: ok i did it. However when i erase the value in edittext it crashes again. Also i want the user to see blank edittext when he opens the app, dont want him to see zeros. Any ideas on how i can do this? Thank You

Comment: `if(myEditText.getText().toString().length()<1) myText = "0";`

Comment: James did what you said it worked fine but the app still crashes when i erase the value i entered

Comment: if you didnt change the code you had to what I wrote above then its probably because your still parsing an empty string which will throw an exception and crash your app. Also null checking your edittexts is not the same as checking to see if they contain empty strings.

Comment: Yes it works fine now. Thank you. however i dont understand what the code means. Can you briefly explain what it does?

Comment: the ? and : symbols are the ternary operators. On the right of the ? you would put the same as inside an if() like 1>0. The true condition is on the left of the : and the false is on the right. so you could use 1>0?true:false to return a true value. 12>14?true:false would return a false value.