# How to multiply two edittext values and automatically display the result in the third EditText in Android

Tags: android

I have written a program for a form which has some 7 to 8 fields , what I want to do is , suppose i am entering a value in EditText 1 as 50 , and in EditText 2 as 60 , the EditText 3 should be automatically calculated to 3000 without clicking any button or performing any event
Can anyone suggest me how to do it ?

```
double a = Double.parseDouble(editDieselRate.getText().toString());
double b = Double.parseDouble(editDieselQty.getText().toString());
double c = a * b;
editAmount.setText(String.valueOf(c));
```

I know i am wrong but just gave it a try , and got number format exception

Thanking You

Comment: You should implement `TextChangedListener` for that... search on _Google_

Comment: Please check this link may be helps you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091425/using-textwatcher-to-get-values-entered-to-two-edittext-and-multiplying-these-va

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code,

```
editDieselRate.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                Double v1 = Double.parseDouble(!editDieselRate.getText().toString().isEmpty() ?
                        editDieselRate.getText().toString() : "0");
                Double v2 = Double.parseDouble(!editDieselQty.getText().toString().isEmpty() ?
                        editDieselQty.getText().toString() : "0");
                Double value = v1 * v2;
                editAmount.setText(value.toString());
            }
        });

        b.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                Double v1 = Double.parseDouble(!editDieselRate.getText().toString().isEmpty() ?
                        editDieselRate.getText().toString() : "0");

                Double v2 = Double.parseDouble(!editDieselQty.getText().toString().isEmpty() ?
                        editDieselQty.getText().toString() : "0");
                Double value = v1 * v2;
                editAmount.setText(value.toString());
            }
        });
```

Also check if the value of editDieselQty or editDieselRate is a number, else you will get an exception. I havent added that check

Answer (score 0):

```
 val mynum1: String = edtPrice.text.toString()
                    val mnum1 = mynum1.toFloat()

                    val mynum2: String = edtQuantity.text.toString()
                    val mnum2 = mynum2.toFloat()

                    val res = mnum1 * mnum2
                    txt_total?.text = res.toString()
```

You can also try this.